# Setting a fragment variable from activity is not working properly

Tags: android, callback, android-fragments

This may be something really simple I'm not seeing, or something very weird I haven't been able to determine why happens.

I have an activity, and 3 fragments.

- `main_fragment` (a map fragment)
- `left_menu_fragment` (listfragment used as main menu)
- `right_menu_fragment` (listfragment used as context menu)

So just imagine something like *facebook app*, main content, and menus left and right.

When I change something in `right_menu_fragment`, I want activity to let `main_fragment` know that I changed something, so I created an interface.

Right menu do the callback, activity receives it, and call the proper function in `main_fragment`, everything works perfectly so far.

Issue is, I am updating an **object instance** from `right_menu_fragment` to another **instance** of same class in `main_fragment` (actually, the variables have same name in both fragments)

When I do the callback, right menu calls this method in activity:

```
@Override
public void changedJourneyPreferences(JourneyPreferences journeyPreferences) {
    if(mapsFragment != null) {
        mapsFragment.setJourneyPreferences(journeyPreferences);
    }
}
```

and the method in `main_fragment` is implemented as follows:

```
public void setJourneyPreferences(JourneyPreferences journeyPreferences) {
    //first log to verify BEFORE THE UPDATE
    boolean foo = false;
    //Some verifications new prefs vs old prefs
    if(some conditions) {
        foo = true;
    }
    //second log to verify I haven't made the update
    this.journeyPreferences = journeyPreferences; //Do the update
    //third log to verify I changed properly
    //If verifications I made previosly are met
    if(foo) {
        //do some other things
    }
}
```

As you see, I verify certain property of the variable I'm receiving to determine if a `boolean` is `true` or `false`, and THEN and ONLY THEN, do the update of the variable.

I added the prints just to verify in runtime what was happening... well, those "other things" that are supposed to met sometimes never happen. I have encountered that once method gets called, it first updates the variable **and then** do the code in the method, or that is what I deduce.

Here is one sample log:

```
first log- old:0 new:0
second log- old:0 new:0
third log- old:0 new:0
first log- old:1 new:1
second log- old:1 new:1
third log- old:1 new:1
first log- old:2 new:2
second log- old:2 new:2
third log- old:2 new:2
```

When it should be something like:

```
first log- old:0 new:0
second log- old:0 new:0
third log- old:0 new:0
first log- old:0 new:1
second log- old:0 new:1
third log- old:1 new:1
first log- old:1 new:2
second log- old:1 new:2
third log- old:2 new:2
```

I tried also to comment the "do the update" line, and then it gets "solved", but of course never does the update.

I tried also to change variables names. EVERYWHERE. In `right_menu_fragment` and `main_fragment`, and in the `setJourneyPreferences` function, receiving a variable name called differently. Didn't work.

So, long story in short: **my method is working as if "do the update" line was *the first one* (as you clearly can see it's not)**

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's better to copy/colle only the relevant parts of your log. With this picture we can't see a thing

Comment: @Yume117 question updated. Hope it's more clear now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the mistake.

When updating the local variable to the one I'm receiving as parameter, I'm assigning my own variable to the one I'm receiving (turns out it's exactly same one from the other fragment).

So I don't know how exactly this works, but my local variable becomes into something *like a pointer*, same Id, same data, same everything. **Two variables in two different fragments pointing to exact same data.** When I am calling `setJourneyPreferences` from activity, variable is updated already and that's the reason I can't verify anything before updating.

Way I solved it, creating a new instance passing values from parameter. A slight change but it makes absolute difference:

Replacing this line:

```
this.journeyPreferences = journeyPreferences; //Do the update
```

With this one:

```
//Do the update
this.journeyPreferences = new JourneyPreferences(
journeyPreferences.getMyLocationAs(),
journeyPreferences.getTimeOfJourneyOpts(),
journeyPreferences.getTimeOfJourney());
```

Copy the data and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

what JourneyPreferences.getMyLocationAs() does? Could your problem be something related with a static variable in that class or something like that?

Comment: It returns an int depending on a preference. It's non static, and as I said, both instances (the one I'm receiving and the one I'm updating are of the same class). I just updated the question to be more clear.

Comment: in first log, are old and new the same instance? I still think it can be related with the values you are logging

Comment: Nope, those are different instances. logs are: old:this.journeyPreferences new:journeyPreferences (the one I'm receiving as parameter)

Comment: You know, I'm digging deeper, and both instances have same Id, but belong to a different fragment instances. How is that even possible?!

Comment: If they are the same instance, then the problem is before doing the setting. Check where you are calling changedJourneyPreferences() and be sure you are not setting or modifying the object JourneyPreferences before calling it.

Comment: Problem was not before doing the setting, it was in that exact line, check answer I ended up giving. Thanks for your observation.